# CodeIgniter - Hyperlink creation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tried to create a hyperlink to another page using anchors however it doesn't seem to work. 
My function is called calendar and its stored in calcontrol.php within a controllers directory.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Calendar extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('calendar');
}

}
?>
```

I have tried other methods but they do not seem to work.

edit : this is my a href 
`<a href="<?php echo site_url('calcontrol/calendar') ?>">Link</a>`

Comment: What is not working here. Make it more descriptive?

Comment: Why not change the `calendar()` function to `index()` you may have to create routes in application > config > routes.php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: If your using codeigniter 3 make sure your file names and class names have first letter upper case.

Comment: How do you try to generate hyperlink.. we don't see anything (code) which try that..

Comment: I have changed it to index. How do I call that in the a href then? do I just call the controller folder name/function name?

Answer (score 0):

Filename and classname must be the same, otherwise CI will not be able to load it. And if using CI 3, make sure your class name and filename are both Ucfirst. If you have everything set up like this, then you should be able to view the page through http://yourdomain.com/calendar/calendar

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You forgot to load url helper. File Calendar.php - nogice capital C if CI3:

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Calendar extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('calendar');
    }

}
```